# Get matching array of items in Elastic Search

Tags: elasticsearch

I have in Elastic Search a list of documents with an array of colors.

```
{
  "documents": [
    {
      "title": "foo",
      "colors": [
        "red",
        "green"
      ]
    },
    {
      "title": "bar",
      "colors": [
        "blue",
        "red"
      ]
    },
    {
      "title": "baz",
      "colors": [
        "blue",
        "green",
        "yellow"
      ]
    }
  ]
}
```

I want to get the documents(s) that match all of their colors in my color pallet.
For example: I have the colors: `red, blue & yellow`. In this case I only want item `bar` because `red & blue` have a matched and it don't have any more as color.
`foo & baz` have more color('s) then my pallet, so I don't want them.

Is this even possible? There are more dirty ways that I can loop through my (php) code, but I would rather have this way. Can somebody help me please?

Comment: Try indexing them as separate documents rather than a single document with an array of elements.

Comment: My bad, yes there are seperate documents.
`
{
  "hits": [
    {
      "title": "foo",
      "colors": [
        "red",
        "green"
      ]
    },
    {
      "title": "bar",
      "colors": [
        "blue",
        "red"
      ]
    },
    {
      "title": "baz",
      "colors": [
        "blue",
        "green",
        "yellow"
      ]
    }
  ]
}
`